# Why disabling a button would cause InvalidOperationException - C#

Tags: c#, button, disabled-control

I recently encountered a situation for which I have no explanation so far

Trying to work on cross-threading operations with winform I wrote a short piece of code to test solutions faster.
I have a form including a progress bar, a a DataGridView and a Button

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        this._progressBar = new ProgressBar { Dock = DockStyle.Top, };
        this._button = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Text = @"&GO!" };
        this._dataGridView = new DataGridView {Dock = DockStyle.Fill,};

        this.Controls.Add(this.ProgressBar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Button);
        this.Controls.Add(this.DataGridView);

        this.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current as WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext;
        this._records = new SpecialBindingList<Record>();
        //this._records = new SpecialBindingList<Record>();
        this.DataGridView.DataSource = this.Records;

        this.Button.Click += this.button_Click;
    }
```

The button has an event OnClick

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dispatcherUI = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        Action action = () =>
        { 
            while (true)
            {

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var value = (this.ProgressBar.Value == this.ProgressBar.Maximum)
                        ? 0
                        : this.ProgressBar.Value + 1;

                    var record = new Record
                    {
                        A = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(),
                        B = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                    };

                    if (Thread.CurrentThread != dispatcherUI.Thread)
                    {
                        dispatcherUI.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ProgressBar.Value = value; }), null);
                    }

                    this.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send((state) => this.Records.Add(record), null);

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                });

            }
        };

        var task = new Task(action);
        task.Start();
        this.Button.Enabled = false;
    }
```

It creates a task, which is filling the progress bar and adding new lines to the grid, then start it and disable the button.

The problem is, is I start the code like this the action `(state) => this.Records.Add(record)` would always throw an `InvalidOperationException` when adding a record to my Bindinglist.

However I realized that if I skip the `this.Button.Enabled = false;` line my code would execute without any problem !
This seems a little odd to me, so I was wondering why modifying a button property would creates an exception on an apparently unrelated operation

Comment: have you tried putting `task.Start();` after `this.Button.Enabled = false;`?

Comment: Where in _your_ code does the Exception get thrown?  You should be able to find this in the stack trace.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I tried it but it does not have any effect.


@Steve I forgot to mention that only the `Records` List update raise the exception, the progress bar value changes are always successful.

Comment: When you get an exception look at the stack trace to learn where the exception is thrown. If that is not enough to solve your problem then come back here with this crucial piece of information.